# while controller isn't working perfectly when testing for multiple users

Tags: jmeter

I have designed a case to wait for specific model name in GET response and then POST data. It is tested and is working fine when only 1 user and 1 loop are set. When the specific model name is found, then proceed to deploy the model.

JSON Extractor

```
$..valid_model_list[?(@.model_name =~ /.*Model-Test-${variable}-${counter}-v1-8k/i)]
```

While Controller

```
${__jexl3("${modelnameresult_matchNr}" != "1",)}
```

However, when I ramp up the test to use 2 users and 2 loops. The result isn't as per expectation.

[image]

Question 1: Why JMeter isn't running the request in sequence when multiple users and loop are set?

How do I design it in a better way to avoid false-positives in results?

Question 2: The GET (TrainedModelsList) constant timer is set to 1 minute and expectation is that it continues running till the end of the test. It seems it just run to a certain period and stopped. What type of timer should be used in this case?

JMeter deployed these model successfully

```
Model-Test-2022-02-28T09:46:40784-0001-v1-8k
Model-Test-2022-02-28T09:46:42785-0002-v1-8k
Model-Test-2022-02-28T09:46:44784-0003-v1-8k
Model-Test-2022-02-28T09:46:46783-0004-v1-8k
```

JMeter start deploy the model and fail although these models are not yet found:

```
Model-Test-2022-02-28T10:02:51745-0006-v1-8k
Model-Test-2022-02-28T10:18:18831-0007-v1-8k
Model-Test-2022-02-28T10:34:21111-0008-v1-8k
Model-Test-2022-02-28T10:50:24376-0009-v1-8k
```

[image]

Updated with view result notes where the problem occurred at second loop:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- `Question 1: Why JMeter isn't run the request in sequence when multiple user and loop is set?`

  Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down, you can add [__threadNum(](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)) function and `${__jm__While Controller__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and you will see it yourself.

  I don't know the full details of the test plan
- `Question 2: The GET (TrainedModelsList) constant timer 1minute and expect it continues running till the end of the test. It seems it just run to a certain period and stopped. What type of timer should be used in this case?`

  I don't know what you're trying to achieve, Constant Timer will create a delay before the requests in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/), if you want to run the requests for one minute either amend the While Controller condition or use [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

Comment: I have tried adding ${__threadNum()} at request name, the view result show a number at each thread, it is just showing the thread number, how do I control them? the test plan req1 post, req2 get and wait while condition (this req 2 should use the variable of user1 only), req3 post (this req 3 should use the variable of user1 only), right now all requests mixed by user 1,2,3,4,5 randomly.

Comment: I updated main post with view result. the problem occurred at second loop.